# Proof that every subgroup of a free group is free (without using algebraic topology)

Tags: group-theory, free-groups

The fact that every subgroup of a free group is free follows quite naturally from the theory of covering spaces applied to graphs.

Is it also possible to proof this theorem without topology, by using only algebraic considerations?

Comment: The original proof is algebraic; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nielsen%E2%80%93Schreier_theorem . But it seems annoying. Note that you can combinatorially develop the theory of covering spaces for graphs (in fact groupoids) completely independent of the topological theory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Of course. You can find such a proof in all textbook on Theory of Groups, e.g.:

Lyndon, Schupp. Combinatorial Group Theory

Magnus, Karrass, Solitar. Combinatorial Group Theory

M.Hall. Theory of groups

A.Kurosh. Theory of groups